# Why record set returns is empty while it is not

Tags: sql, sqlite, nested

There is data in table `piyasa_kontrol` and `ilaclar`. And there is coupling over ilac_id and id for `LEFT JOIN`. But there is no returning records when query run.

```
SELECT ilaclar.ilac_adi AS ilAdi
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM piyasa_kontrol
      WHERE pk_yil=2013
      AND pk_ay IN (4, 5, 6)) AS pik
LEFT JOIN ilaclar ON pik.ilac_id = ilaclar.id
```

What is the problemn here? Thank you.

Comment: This query works fine in Navicat SQLite but doesn't work in HTA application with vbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `ilacc_adi` field has empty values is because you are using a `left outer join`.

There are cases where there is no matching record.  If you used an `inner join` you would not see the row at all.  With a `left outer join` you get a NULL value.

To debug this, but in the join id to see where the mon-matches are occurring:

```
SELECT pik.ilac_id,  ilaclar.ilac_adi AS ilAdi
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM piyasa_kontrol
      WHERE pk_yil=2013
      AND pk_ay IN (4, 5, 6)) AS pik
LEFT JOIN ilaclar ON pik.ilac_id = ilaclar.id
```

Comment: Nothing changes. Same recordset returned. :/

Comment: @caglaror . . . Yes, but now you can see which `ilac_id`s are in `piyasa_lcontrol` but not in `ilaclar`.  This is probably the root of your problem -- a data issue, not a query issue.

Comment: There are many coupling id numbers. When have a look at two table side-by-side i can see them. http://goo.gl/K7ffu , http://goo.gl/Ykebi, http://goo.gl/59xiP are the tables screenshots.

Comment: You are right. I was looking for primer tables usual id number as ilac_id, but it is not it is :) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is how you troubleshoot stuff like this.  Step 1.

```
select count(*)
from piyasa_kontrol
```

If that gives you more than 0, Step 2

```
select count(*)
from piyasa_kontrol 
pk_yil=2013
```

Carry on until your query returns 0.  Then you'll know what's causing that to occur.

Comment: Sorry i told wrong. Query returns full but i need `ilac_adi` field. This field returns emtyp while others fill full.